# Saving a SVG file to a variable in JavaScript with multiple images and referencing each image and appending them individually

Tags: javascript, svg, chess

Please tell me if there is a better way to do this.

So I am building a chess game and I want to run a function that loops through the board and places all the images for the pieces in their starting places. 
Now I read that somewhere on the Internet that I could reference the id tag in the SVG file. So I want to save the image in a variable then reference that file and then reference that specific image then place that image on the board.

I tried looking this up and asking my teachers to no avail.

https://repl.it/@DangeloS/WoefulMetallicKeyboard

I want pictures of pieces to appear on the board

Answer (score 0):

Great start so far...

This code won't work on SO due to CORs restrictions for the SVG placeholder images, but I think you'll get the idea.

Here is an array of objects containing a URL and `id` of an element to place the SVG image into. This code simply loops through the images and displays them in the appropriate location.

Now to address the other part of your question about loading this up into variables etc, you can do that on the fly using the Element's innerHTML.

Hope this help and best of luck to you.

```js
let svgCollection = [{
  url: "https://placeholder.pics/svg/150",
  placement: 'spot1'
}, {
  url: "https://placeholder.pics/svg/150",
  placement: 'spot2'
}];

$.each(svgCollection, (svg) => {
  $.get(svg.url, function(data) {
    $(svg.placement).append(data["documentElement"]);
  })
});
```

```css
#spot2 {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#spot1 {
  border: 1px green solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spot1">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="spot2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Well what is SO and CORS. And are you saying that I should have separate image files instead of 1? I don't fully understand what you're saying, or maybe I'm just thinking too hard.

Comment: didn't mean to talk past you. SO = Stackoverflow; what I meant is the code above won't work on this site, but will work fine in your code. The title of your post says _"multiple images"_ and your question refers to _"all the images"_ and you are _"creating a chess game"_ - so yeah, a rook is different that a pawn visually. Which means different SVG files. But perhaps I misunderstood your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this SVG file: [cat.svg](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg). This will give you an empty screen. All the items are hidden.

However if you open the file in view-source this is how it looks inside:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100px" height="100px"  viewBox="0 0 225 225">

<style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[  
    svg > svg:not(:target) {
    display: none;
    }
     ]]> 
</style>
<desc>
<g id="cat">
<path id="body" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M121.506 ... 108.953z"/>
<path id="head" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M129.747,18.651 ... 81.453z"/>
</g>
</desc>
<svg version="1.1" id="blackcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="black" />
</svg>
<svg version="1.1" id="redcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="red" />
</svg>

</svg>
```

Inside you have two other svg elements with an id each. In the CSS (this is important) all the svg elements inside the main svg have `display:none` unless the element is the target.
For example this is targeting the red cat:  `src="https://path/cat.svg#redcat"`

If you want to see the red cat you can do this:

```html
<img width="50" height ="50" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat" />
```

I hope this is what you were asking.